# How to change the name displayed in conky?

Tags: conky

I have set a infinity conky theme but am helpless in changing the name that comes in the left bottom corner since it is of its developer.but i want to make it more personalized thus can you please tell me where to where to make the changes.
pls help

Comment: If it is text, it is as simple as editing the .conkyrc file which should be in your ĥome folder (note it might be hidden). If it is not, it night be a picture. Nobody can tell without seeing the .conkyrc file and the corresponding conky. Maybe this question is better suited for a forum...

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, ~/.conkyrc is where the configuration lives.

Find the string you wish to change in the second section under "TEXT" and 
edit it.

Note that you may not have this file. When you install conky it installs /etc/conky/etc/conky/ as it's primary default conky IF ~/.conkyrc does not exist. You can find numerous configuration examples on the web, for instance [here.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=39906)

Sources: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=867076

https://lusule.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/how-to-4/